# How to calculate sensor_msgs/LaserScan data?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, sensor-msgs, 2dlaserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have made a bag: 2021-02-15-11-32-28.bag and converted it in the: rplidarA1.csv File.
So I have 2 Mb data and the following fields:
%time
field.header.seq
field.header.stamp
field.header.frame_id
field.angle_min
field.angle_max
field.angle_increment
field.time_increment
field.scan_time
field.range_min
field.range_max
field.ranges0 bis field.ranges719
field.intensity

My question:
With which of these fields, I can calculate the distance to a object ?

I real appreciate your comments :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372504/how-to-calculate-sensor_msgs/laserscan-data-?/) by [Tricia279](https://answers.ros.org/users/60504/tricia279/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Lidar's laserscan/ranges work in this way:

It detects and record in terms of an array in a string of Float32.

So in the lets say the object is 2 meters between the Lidar 0 degree to 3 degree:

Range: [2.0 2.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ....]

More on: http://docs.ros.org/en/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) with karma: 98 on 2021-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) on 2021-02-26**:
As @loguna have mentioned, but you should notice that the angle increment play a role in it. In @loguna example, the angle_increment is 1 degree, assumed that the measure unit of angle_increment is degree(but it's rad)

**Comment by [Tricia279](https://answers.ros.org/users/60504/tricia279/) on 2021-03-02**:
@loguna:
I have 3 additional questions:
The "range" in your example is it the field_range ? range_min or range_max ?
I use RViz: How I can set the angle in rad there ? and
How I can get these Range: [2.0 2.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ....] ?

**Comment by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) on 2021-03-03**:
Its in Field range.
So the lidar spins 360 degree, it collects signals and place them into an array in meters. So lets say the Lidar collect a signal per degree (Check with your Lidar manufacturer), your array should contain [360] meters values. To obtain the signal, import the LaserScan from sensor_msgs.msg.
Than try printing "LaserScan.ranges".

If you wish to detect obstacle at a specific direction:
The way i usually do is place an object in front of the Lidar.
Next I set a random value like
LaserScan.range[180] to see if the lidar did pick up the object. If it didnt, i change the "value" of LaserScan.range[value] until i get a hit.

N usually 360 degree Lidar is use more towards mapping and not really to detect obstacles at a specific direction. Hence in RVIZ, it will show all the points in 360 degree.